# Backward entailment

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

An valid argument (p⊩c) is one where the premises (p) necessarily lead to the conclusion (c) , with truth table one check  its validity by showing that p⟹c is a tautology ( ⊩p⟹c ) .in such manner we can deduce the conclusion B from the set of premises { A , A⟹B } by showing that ⊩ (A ∧ (A⟹B)) ⟹ B is tautology. My question is whether it is possible to proceed backward from a tautology to a valid argument

Comment: Are you familiar with the **deduction theorem**?

Comment: The validity of argument can be defined in two types of context : one is the proof system  in witch we use deductive system to produce theorem from a  set of axioms (can be empty) and a set of inference rules   , the second context uses models ,  my question falls within the second context using truth table

Comment: OK, based on that it sounds like you're asking whether semantic and syntactic arguments coincide (we can prove something via truth tables iff we can prove it via our deduction system); is that correct? If so, the answer is **yes** and this is the **soundness/completeness theorem**.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase:

One of the rules in logic is from a deduction $A \vdash B$ you get an inference $\vdash A \to B$. The question is can you get the deduction back from the inference?

The answer is yes. Here are the steps:

1. From $\vdash A \to B$ you get $A \vdash A \to B$ by weakening the empty premise.
2. $A \vdash A$.
3. Using Modus Ponens (MP) you get $A \vdash B$.

This is the Deduction Theorem. Sorry I didn't recognize this in my previous answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. "$A\vdash B\iff\vdash A\rightarrow B$" [is a basic logical property](https://www3.nd.edu/~cfranks/dt.pdf), and indeed you have to look pretty far afield to find [logics in which it fails](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132268/deduction-theorem). What exactly are you claiming here?

Comment: In fact, it's actually the *other* direction - getting $\vdash A\rightarrow B$ from $A\vdash B$ - which is more interesting. Getting $A\vdash B$ from $\vdash A\rightarrow B$ is a consequence of merely *monotonicity*, *reflexivity*, and *modus ponens*: if $\vdash A\rightarrow B$ then we have $A\vdash A\rightarrow B$ by monotonicity, but reflexivity gives us also $A\vdash A$ and combining these we get via modus ponens that $A\vdash B$. (You also seem to be using "$\vdash$" in two different ways - *deduction* versus *inference*.) I think you may need to explain this answer further.

Comment: There *is* a distinction between saying ""$A\rightarrow B$" is true" (which is a statement about *some fixed model $M$*) and ""$A\vdash B$" is a valid sequent" (which is equivalent to $B$ being true in *every* model in which $A$ is true, which is a stronger claim than merely $B$ being true in $M$ specifically if $A$ is true in $M$ specifically), and a computational interpretation can make this fairly similar to the idea at the end of your answer. But that's not relevant here, since we're looking at $\vdash A\rightarrow B$ and not $A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You are absolutely right! Sorry I didn't recognize that. I was thinking too hard about the computational meaning of the type they represent. Nevertheless in type theory or intuitionistic logic the deduction theorem still holds! Thanks for pointing out there are logics in which the deduction theorem fails, that looks interesting!

Comment: This only works for conditionals though.  Not all tautologies are conditionals.

Comment: So I think you've asked a different question than what got asked.

Answer (score 1):

For a single tautology?  Yes.  Using one-half of the deduction meta-theorem we can move from a tautological *conditional* to a valid argument.  Prefix notation comes as preferable for this discussion, since the type of tautology according to its main connective comes as relevant.  We can move from some tautology $\vdash$ ($\rightarrow$ A B) to A $\vdash$ B (note A and B are not propositional variables).

For an arbitrary tautology?  No.  At least not in any straightforward way.  There is no valid argument that any disjunction, conjunction, or equivalence translates into.  For example, the tautology, in Polish notation,

E EEpqr EpEqr (equivalence associates)

doesn't have any straightforward translation into a valid argument. At least not if the equivalence connective 'E' comes as a primitive connective.

Comment: what do you mean by a single and arabitrary tautology?

Comment: @sostar By 'a single tautology' I mean that there exists at least one tautology that works that way.  By an 'arbitrary tautology' I mean that for any given tautology, it will not work that way.